# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visible') : amcharts throwing typeerror while using json based config

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to create a line chart with bullets using version4 amcharts, below is what my config looks like(only relevant portion shown):

```
series: [
    {
      type: "LineSeries",
      visible: true,
      bullets: [
        {
          type: "Bullet",
          children: [
            {
              type: "Circle",
              width: 10,
              height: 10
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      name: "Client",
      tooltipText: "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY.formatNumber('#,###.##')}[/]",
      dataFields: {
        categoryX: "VC Firm",
        valueY: "Client"
      },
    }
  ],
```

I am supposed to see a line graph with bullets at each plotted data point. But the output only has a normal line chart with no bullets and not hover I am receiving the below error :

```
"XYSeries.ts:2057 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visible')
    at XYSeries.showTooltipAtDataItem (XYSeries.ts:2057:1)
    at XYSeries.showTooltipAtPosition (XYSeries.ts:1983:1)
    at XYChart.ts:1359:1
    at Module.each (Array.ts:95:1)
    at List.each (List.ts:915:1)
    at XYChart.showSeriesTooltip (XYChart.ts:1352:1)
    at XYChart.handleCursorPositionChange (XYChart.ts:1160:1)
    at Object.dispatch (EventDispatcher.ts:444:1)
    at EventDispatcher.ts:346:1
    at triggerIdle (AsyncPending.ts:162:1)"
```